# Starting dev server and moving to component fails onMount fetch requests

Tags: mongodb, get, fetch, vite, sveltekit

I'm working on my first project with sveltekit/vite and by it learning web dev stuff in general. Error occurs to my which I really don't understand after trying to solve this or even look for solution.

I'm using kit @0.0.1 and vite v2.9.14.

I'm using this function in lib/mongodb/db.ts to connect to my database :

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
const { MONGODB_URI, MONGODB_DB } = process.env;

if (!MONGODB_URI) {
    throw new Error('Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable inside .env.local');
}

if (!MONGODB_DB) {
    throw new Error('Please define the MONGODB_DB environment variable inside .env.local');
}

let cached = global.mongo;
if (!cached) cached = global.mongo = {};

export async function connectToDatabase() {
    if (cached.conn) return cached.conn;
    if (!cached.promise) {
        const conn: any = {};
        const opts = {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        };
        cached.promise = MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts)
            .then((client: any) => {
                conn.client = client;
                return client.db(MONGODB_DB);
            })
            .then((db) => {
                conn.db = db;
                cached.conn = conn;
            });
    }
    await cached.promise;
    return cached.conn.db;
}
```

Then by using this endpoint in src/routes/Cities/index.ts :

```
import { connectToDatabase } from '$lib/mongodb/db';

export async function get() {
    try {
        const dbConnection = await connectToDatabase();
        const db = dbConnection.db;
        const collection = await db.collection('Cities');
        const query = await collection.find({}).toArray();
        return {
            status: 200,
            body: {
                query
            }
        };
    } catch (err: any) {
        return {
            status: 500,
            body: {
                error: err.message
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Fetch data from the database by this onMount function in my src/routes/places.svelte component :

```
    onMount(async () => {
        fetch('/Cities')
            .then((response) =>  response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                $citiesArr = data.query;
                gotCities = true;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    });
```

The problem is as follows, when I start the dev server and go to that component this fetch request ends with an error :

```
start.js:286 
GET http://localhost:3000/Cities 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

But then when I refresh the page without restarting the dev server, my data fetches properly, without any error, it just fetches and I can go back and forth between components, and refresh the page again: no error happens.

Could someone please explain to me (big backend noob) why it works like this ? I just want to learn and really can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Sveltekit has changed it's port number from 3000 to 5173 try running from http://localhost:5173/Cities
https://vitejs.dev/blog/announcing-vite3.html#dev-improvements